# Empty Shoelace Select with two way binding in Svelte

Tags: select, svelte, web-component, two-way-binding, shoelace

I cannot empty previous selection when changing options between related Shoelace Selects in Svelte. I tried to force Shoelace select value but it didn't work, maybe I shouldn't use two-way binding or there is another workaround when working with Shoelace and Svelte.

I have an array of trees, where trees have branches.

```html
<script>
    import { trees } from './data'
    import Select from './Select.svelte'
    
    let id_trees = '1'
    let id_branches = '1'
    
    $: branches = trees.find(tree => tree.id == id_trees).branches
</script>


<Select label="Trees" bind:value={id_trees}>
   {#each trees as { id, name }}
     <sl-option value={id}>{name}</sl-option>
   {/each}
</Select>

<Select label="Branches" bind:value={id_branches}>
   {#each branches as { id, name }}
     <sl-option value={id}>{name}</sl-option>
   {/each}
</Select>
```

If I change from tree A to B and C **render** works as expected:

[image]

but if I go back to tree A then branch C1 remains:

[image]

Here a minimal working example:

https://svelte.dev/repl/367d0371c1c34b09912f3a2a381c8234?version=4.2.10

**Update: variable for the branch selection remains the same**

`key` and object identity solutions are wonderful but they only affects the render. I though using object identity would empty the real value but it doesn't. How can we empty the `id_branches` selection?

Same working example where I chose different ids to show that changing trees doesn't empty/change id_branches:

https://svelte.dev/repl/94f43b27eb22435198643b2fe92206b5?version=4.2.10

**Solution:**

brunnerh answer and comments solved the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component does not appear to update based on the text content change of the option (the `value` potentially remains the same).

In situations like this, a simple workaround is to recreate the affected part of the component via [`{#key}`](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#key). So in this case you could do this:

```html
{#key branches}
    <Select label="Branches" bind:value={id_branches}>
       {#each branches as { id, name }}
             <sl-option value={id}>{name}</sl-option>
       {/each}
    </Select>
{/key}
```

This way, the dependent select is fully updated if its options list changes.

---

You also can force the recreation of the options in the `{#each}` by providing a key ([see docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each)) that can distinguish between the branch items of the different trees, e.g. by using the object identity of the items:

```html
<Select label="Branches" bind:value={id_branches}>
   {#each branches as item (item)}
     {@const { id, name } = item}
     <sl-option value={id}>{name}</sl-option>
   {/each}
</Select>
```

This however will cause the selection to be cleared on tree change, even if the option `value` would exist.

Comment: Thank you so much, wonderful answer! But is it possible to make second selection empty `id_branches = ''`? I mean by default we have `id_branches = '1'` and if we change trees `id_branches` remains unchanged, even though we don't have those options anymore

Comment: You could just add another reactive statement that resets the value, along the lines of `$: if (branches.find(...) == null) id_branches = '';`.

Comment: Thank so much I really appreciate your awesome expertise, but why is not possible to just add a reactive statement that reset the value every time only branches change: `$: (branches && (id_branches = ''))` when id_branches change the reactive statement is also triggered

Comment: Svelte uses static analysis to determine what gets invalidated and it generally tends to invalidate more than necessary. Sometimes this can cause issues, though. In Svelte 5 the whole reactivity system will change to be based on runtime logic rather than analysis which will be more accurate and extend to function calls. Right now you could use the limitation that code inside a function call does not affect reactive statements to limit when the statement is executed. E.g. extract the reset to a function: `const reset = () => id_branches = '';` and add `$: branches, reset();`.

Comment: Direct to the point, amazing, this solved the issue, thank you so much brunnerh! Can't wait for Svelte 5!